# Unable to add TAB character to post?

Tags: plugins, posts, shortcode, wysiwyg, tabs

I am using the CodeColorer plugin to display source code in my WordPress. I am trying to have my code indented so that it displays properly on the website. However, when I try to add the following code to the WYSIWYG editor:

```
[cc lang="csharp"]
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LittleSoftwareStats
{
    public static class Config
    {
        public static bool Enabled { get; set; }

        internal static string ApiUrl
        {
            get
            {
                UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder((Config.ApiSecure) ? ("https") : ("http"), Config.ApiHost, Config.ApiPort, Config.ApiPath);

                return uri.ToString();
            }
        }
        internal static string AppId { get; set; }
        internal static string AppVer { get; set; }

        internal const string ApiHost = "stats.yourwebsitehere.com";
        internal const int ApiPort = 80;
        internal const bool ApiSecure = false;
        internal const string ApiPath = "api."+ApiFormat;

        internal const string ApiFormat = "json";
        internal const string ApiUserAgent = "LittleSoftwareStatsNET";
        internal const int ApiTimeout = 25000;
    }
}
[/cc]
```

When I update it, the code then becomes:

```
[cc lang="csharp"]
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LittleSoftwareStats
{
public static class Config
{
public static bool Enabled { get; set; }

internal static string ApiUrl
{
get
{
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder((Config.ApiSecure) ? ("https") : ("http"), Config.ApiHost, Config.ApiPort, Config.ApiPath);

return uri.ToString();
}
}
internal static string AppId { get; set; }
internal static string AppVer { get; set; }

internal const string ApiHost = "stats.yourwebsitehere.com";
internal const int ApiPort = 80;
internal const bool ApiSecure = false;
internal const string ApiPath = "api."+ApiFormat;

internal const string ApiFormat = "json";
internal const string ApiUserAgent = "LittleSoftwareStatsNET";
internal const int ApiTimeout = 25000;
}
}
[/cc]
```

I have also tried replacing the spaces with `&nbsp;`, and `&#09;` and the actual TAB character. If I add the TAB character in the Text editor then it will stay but once when I switch it to the Visual editor then it is all removed. I  was wondering if anyone knows a trick to keeping the code indented or if there's someway to fix it (without modifying the CodeColorer plugin)?

Comment: TinyMCE isn’t made for custom HTML formatting. You should avoid it completely. Use the HTML editor, now misnamed _Text_.

Comment: Or you can use custom post meta; I do that to have absolute control and to ensure plugins don't interfere. Check out http://pea.rs/ which uses post meta well for this purpose. Adding syntax highlighting via http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I figured it out. I installed [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) and [SyntaxHighlighter TinyMCE Button](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter-tinymce-button). When I select the code and use the TinyMCE button to highlight it, the spaces seem to stay. This also works in both TinyMCE's Visual and Text editors.